# Invoke a Lambda function with S3 payload from boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to invoke a Lambda function that accepts an S3 path. Below sample code of the lambda function.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key = "mykey/output/model.tar.gz"

    model = load_model(bucket, key)
    somecalc = some_func(model)

    result = {'mycalc': json.dumps(somecalc)}

    return result
```

I need to invoke this handler from my client code using boto3. I know I can do a request like below

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='mylambda_function',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    LogType='Tail',
    ClientContext='myContext',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='1'
)
```

But I am not sure how to specify an S3 path in the payload. Looks like it is expecting a JSON.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a payload like so:

```
payload = json.dumps({ 'bucket': 'myS3Bucket' })

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='mylambda_function',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    LogType='Tail',
    ClientContext='myContext',
    Payload=payload,
    Qualifier='1'
)
```

And access the payload properties in your lamdba handler like so:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['bucket'] # pull from 'event' argument
    key = "mykey/output/model.tar.gz"

    model = load_model(bucket, key)
    somecalc = some_func(model)

    result = {'mycalc': json.dumps(somecalc)}

    return result
```